# Black-list the "conditional" tag

Tags: support, tags

There were 17 questions using [conditional](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditional) where the tag was used to generally mean "something that needs to conditionally happen/be true." As such, the tag is not helpful at all. If there are some conditions that need to be verified, such conditions should be described in the questions, but they don't deserve a tag, as [conditional](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditional) doesn't change the given answers, nor does it reach a specific audience (i.e. there aren't experts in conditional staff).

The 17 questions where asked:

- 1 in the last 30 days
- 5 in the past 3 months
- 8 in the current year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a simple retagging fixed your issue here. :)

If the tag goes out of control and can't be managed with timely retags, we can talk blacklisting.